# Command for beautiful quoting

Tags: bash

Sometimes I need to quote an entire command line for future evaluation. Usually I do that with:

```
printf "%q " "$@"
```

That's short and sweet but the output look awful. Most of the time this doesn't matter but in occasions I want to show it to the user. For example, in a history of executed commands menu that allows for re-execution of entries. That being the case, I would like to quote in a more readable form (closer to what the user itself would have done if he were in charge of quoting). So this:

```
search 'Wordreference (eng->spa)' utter
```

would be preferable to this:

```
search Wordreference\ \(eng-\>spa\) utter
```

In order to get the first quoted form I could iterate `"$@"` and do something like what follows for each argument:

```
[[ $arg == *\ * ]] && arg="'"${arg//\'/\'\\\'\'}"'"
```

This is not difficult at all but it involves a loop, a conditional string transformation and concatenation of the result of each iteration.

I wonder if there is a more "batteries included" command to do this kind of transformation out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried http://unix.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

In the same way you use `eval` to later execute the string, you can use `eval` to print it:

```
eval "echo $yourstring"
```

This will remove the shell escapes but keep your variable intact.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even begin to see how this answers the question. It's not a string I'm quoting but an array. Moreover, `eval "echo ..."` will never add a level of quoting, quite the contrary the echoing of the unquoted expansion of `yourstring` will remove quoting.